# How do I create a button, that on press, triggers a refresh to the sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The title is basically it. I've seen it done before, all in google apps script and only on google sheets. I just can neither find the reference nor any other material matching what I'm trying to do. I know very little about google apps script, but I tried using this (I swear I tried.)

```
function myFunction() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
 if(sheet.getRange('H7') == true) {
   SpreadsheetApp.flush
 }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It's not clear what you are trying to do... start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets. If you need further help, please add more details about what do you expect to happen when the button is clicked.

Comment: Here is an article on how to make a button and run a script [Buttons in Google Sheets](https://spreadsheet.dev/buttons-in-google-sheets).  But I doubt your `myFunction` will do anything.  `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` is intended to make sure all `setValues()` and similar set methods have been flushed from cache and committed to the spreadsheet.  Your script doesn't do any of that unless called from another function.

Comment: Rubén Yeah, sorry about that. The basic idea is to have a checkbox, or button, trigger a code refresh on google sheets. The only thing I remember is that it worked off the True/False checkbox. I dont remember for sure, but I'm almost positive that it did not refresh the page client side, it only made the code force refresh.